# Persist form values between pages

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

In my PhoneGap app I have a form page in which there is a contacts button. When the user clicks it the contacts page appears to select a contact and then returns to the form to submit it. In the JSFiddle when returning to the form the entered data still in the form, but in my app when I return to the form all the entered data has been removed so the user needs to fill the form again.

How can I keep the entered form data in the fields when returning to it from the contacts page?

When the user clicks the done button in the contacts page I use this code to pass the selected data to the formPage.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyQUy/31/)

```
$('#Done').on('click', function(){   
    $.mobile.changePage('FormPage.html', {
        dataUrl: 'FormPage.html?paremeter=' + selectedContact + ' ',
        data: {
            'paremeter': '' + selectedContact + ''
        },
        reloadPage: false,
        changeHash: false
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Can you put your contacts in a jQM popup instead of a separate page?

Comment: thanks for your reply , because i have 100 contacts i had to put the contacts list in a separate page

Comment: @ ezanker can i make a jQM popup of 100 list element ?? how can i do that ? please can you help me?

Comment: i wrote up an answer for you.

Comment: thank you very much , i will try it and i hope it work in my App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a popup instead of a separate page.

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LyQUy/33/)**

Your page 2 is now a popup within the first page. It includes a DIV that is scrollable and a listview which is dynamically populated with 100 items:

```
<div data-role="popup"  id="page2" data-position-to="window">
     <div  id="scrollDiv">
         <ul data-role="listview" id="contactsList">
         </ul>
     <div>
</div>

#scrollDiv{
    max-height: 450px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

On pageinit I add 100 contacts and then creat a click handler for the contacts that writes the selected contact id back to a field in the form and closes the popup:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#FormPage", function(){
    var contactsList;
    for (var i = 0; i< 100; i++){     
        contactsList += '<li><a href="#" class="contactLink" data-contactid="' + i + '">contact ' + i + '</a></li>';
    }
    $("#contactsList").append($(contactsList));
    $("#contactsList").listview("refresh");

    $(".contactLink").on("click", function(){    
        var msg = 'you selected contact: id = ';
        msg += $(this).data("contactid");            
        $("#selContact").val(msg);
        $("#page2").popup( "close" )
    });
});
```